# formula criteria is not working for updated record, it's working for New record

Tags: formula, process-builder

Here is my formal for PB, it's firing when record is created but not when record is updates with `released__c/status__c` changes, am i missing some thing?

```
OR(
 AND( ISNEW(), NOT(ISBLANK([ticket__c].ticket_Event__c ))),
 AND(NOT(ISNEW()),NOT(ISBLANK([ticket__c].ticket_Event__c )),
      OR(
            ISCHANGED([ticket__c].released__c ),ISCHANGED([ticket__c].status__c )
         )
     )
)
```

Comment: yes, `released__c`  & `status__c` both are pick list fields

Answer (score 1):

Your formula seems good to me. Have you double checked that your process builder start the process :

> When a record is created or edited

And not :

> Only when a record is created

That could be the issue.

Comment: option with "When a record is created or edited" even though is not firing